# How to import class property in another file - Vue/Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

src/middlewares/auth.ts file:

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

export default class AuthGuard extends Vue {
  public guest(to: any, from: any, next: any): void {
    if (this.$store.state.authenticated) {
      next()
      console.log('authenticated')
    } else {
      next({
        path: '/dashboard'
      })
      console.log('not authenticated')
    }
  }
}
```

Same auth.ts as above, but in JS version:

```
export default {
 guest(to, from, next) {
    if (this.$store.state.authenticated) {
      next()
      console.log('authenticated')
    } else {
      next({
        path: '/dashboard'
      })
      console.log('not authenticated')
    }
  }
}
```

In JS it works as intended, but not with Typescript.

I want to import this class in AuthRoutes.ts:

```
import Guard from '@/middlewares/auth'

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('@/views/Login.vue'),
    beforeEnter: Guard.guest
  }
]
```

But i'm getting an error: "Property 'guest' does not exist on type 'typeof AuthGuard'." Still can't wrap my head around these TS types. What do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

## Do not use `beforeEnter` if you need access to the instance.

The `property` exists on the `component instance`, not on the `class definition`.

`beforeEnter` does not have access to the instance.

Put your logic in the `created()` or `mounted()` method of the component, and prefix it with `this.`.

## Use `beforeRouteEnter` and `beforeRouteUpdate` for access to component's `this`.

**The beforeRouteEnter guard does NOT have access to this**, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.

**However, you can access the instance by passing a callback to next**. The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed, and the component instance will be passed to the callback as the argument:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    // access to component instance via `vm`
  })
}
```

So for your example

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    vm.guest
  })
}
```

And for route changes that preserve the component:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  this.guest
}
```

## Official Documentation

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
    // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
    // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
  },
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // called when the route that renders this component has changed,
    // but this component is reused in the new route.
    // For example, for a route with dynamic params `/foo/:id`, when we
    // navigate between `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, the same `Foo` component instance
    // will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens.
    // has access to `this` component instance.
  },
```

Comment: What if i want to use class definition? I should skip `extends Vue` then. But how do i access `this.$store` without explicitly importing it.

Comment: Your component is not created until after the routing.  I will add more to my solution using `beforeRouteUpdate`

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but i'm not experiencing issue with `beforeEnter`. My issue is related to a typescript types.